# $watchCollection not firing when updating values in model

Tags: angularjs

I have [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/piRaPQDh7mOd8CvJTAvy?p=preview), is it somewhat possible to `$watch` the whole `foos` every time the fields are changed?

It looks like the `console.log()` is only called when you press the "Insert Foo" button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `$watch` with deep object watch true instead of using `$watchCollection`.

**$watchCollection()**

> `$watchCollection()` function was added for collection oriented change
>   management, it only gets called when Item has been removed or added
>   while $watch performs dirty checking an called on any value change in
>   any of its collection member.

**$watch()**

> The $watch() function takes a third, optional argument for "object
>   equality." If you pass-in "true" for this argument, AngularJS will
>   actually perform a deep-object-tree comparison.

**Code**

```
$scope.$watch('foos', function(v) {
  console.log('baz');
},true)
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cBBheeImcZXnTuSGP0nc?p=preview)